# Where does linux subsystem for windows look for SSH keys?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, location, default, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have had problems using **sftp** and other services on the **Linux Subsystem for Windows**, as I have not been able to point the services to the correct ssh-folder.

I have been using the same setup as in linux by placing by keys in the folder:

```
/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

However, this is not the folder that **sftp** etc. look in by default on the subsystem! I have looked at multiple posts on the topic, and only found posts pointing to this setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct **default** folder to place your ssh-key in for them to work on the subsystem for linux is:

```
C:\Users\myuser\.ssh\id_rsa
```

And if you are on the subsystem the path is:

```
/mnt/c/Users/H52Z/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I hope this solves the problem for eveyone who has also been struggeling with the setup.

Comment: Optional C:\Users\WINDOWS_USERNAME\AppData\Local\lxss\home\LINUX_USERNAME\.ssh